# How to fix an error when changing Gemfile in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, gemfile

I'm new to rails and I keep running into an error when I edit the Gemfile to the below.  It can also be found under Listing 2.1 at this tutorial: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#sec-planning_the_application

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.7'
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
end
# Gems used only for assets and not required # in production environments by default. 
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

When I type 'bundle install' in the terminal, I get an error that says:

```
Gemfile syntax error:
group :deve...3.2.7'ygems.org'
...                               ^
```

Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Your Gemfile looks fine, but that error is pretty suspect. Is that the full error? Are you sure your Gemfile is not corrupt in some way?

Comment: How would I check if the file is corrupt?

Comment: Just open it. The error is telling you that you have a syntax error, so almost certainly you have some garbled text in your Gemfile. If you have it open in an editor, are you sure you're looking at the same file? Are you sure that you haven't fixed the problem and neglected to save the file? etc. etc.

Comment: Have you tried recreating the gemfile and copying it over the existing one?